# Reading column headers using csv.DictReader and without the fieldnames() method

Tags: python, csv

I have the following (toy) data in a csv file named 'my_file.csv':

```
Person  City          State  Age
John    Los Angeles   CA     34 
Mary    Boston        MA     27 
Phil    London        N/A    30
```

I'd like to be able to print a list of the headers. I'm using the following to create a `reader` object, then printing the `fieldnames`:

```
import csv
filepath = my_file.csv"
col_names = [] 

with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    print(reader.fieldnames)
```

Is it possible to print the field names **without** using the `fieldnames`() method? (e.g. iterating over `reader` and accessing the dictionary keys in some way)

Thanks!

Comment: just wonder if you could do `reader = dict(reader)` then do `reader.keys()`

Comment: Why can't you use `fieldnames`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a particularly bizarre constraint to be able to use `DictReader` but not use its `fieldnames` value. Anyway, just open the csv file as a normal CSV and read the first row - this gives you the field names.

```
import csv
filepath = my_file.csv"

with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        headerrow = list(row)
        break
    print(headerrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply read the text files with `readlines` and split the first line using `.split()` with your separator.

Comment: This may work for naive cases, but will fail e.g. if a field contains the separator character.

Comment: you are right but there must be some unambiguous splitting methodology which I am not sure what it is from the requirements

Comment: I'd like to be able to iterate over the "keys", stuff them into a list, then print the list.  But, I'm not sure if this is possible.  Yes, I know about `fieldnames` (we get that one for free).

Comment: so if you have the logic to separate them, just read the first line and separate/

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with.  I know how to iterate over the entire dict and append.  But, that results in a lot of extraneous data.  I don't know how to get only the first line.